# Glass cup + Water not rendering correctly, weird lines

Tags: rendering

[image: ..]

I'm just starting to learn Blender and am following Blender Guru's donut tutorial. I just "filled" the glass cup with water and everything looks correct as far as I know but when I render it, the water doesn't look right and there are some weird horizontal lines going on. As I said, I'm very new and don't really know what to look for.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to access the blender file or the image. The links you provided just redirected me to a bunch of irrelevant websites. 

Stack Exchange allows you to add images directly to the question, and Blend Exchange is a great place for storing .blend files for posts. Link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please use this site tools for images and files...

Comment: @NullPointerException Strange, the links work for me. But I added a download link for BlendExchange, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Lines in transparent materials are a telltale sign of intersections with other objects. This was no exception.

To verify that there were intersections between the liquid and cup objects, I took these steps to generate a mesh that resembles the intersections:

1. Tab out of edit mode. This only works in object mode.
2. Select the liquid.
3. Hit the "Modifier Properties" tab of the properties window.
4. Create a new Boolean modifier (it's under the Generate group) with the following properties.

- Operation: Difference
- Object: Cup
- Overlap Threshold: 0

Below is the screenshot of the results:

[image: Intersections]

Yep, the cup and liquid definitely intersect. And notice how those lines match the lines in the render.

One way to fix the problem is by shrinking the liquid in the x and y axes. Here's how I did it:

1. Remove the Boolean modifier (that was just to see the intersections)
2. Select the liquid and *only* the liquid.
3. Tab into edit mode
4. Hit `a` to select all vertices
5. Hit `s` to scale them
6. Hit `shift` and `z` to lock the transformation in the Z axis.
7. Enter `0.99`.
8. Tab out of edit mode.

Now the cup should look like this:
[image: No noticeable difference since the first image]

At first glance, it doesn't look like anything changed. But when you render the scene...
[image: Yay, no lines!]
...no more lines!

One other thing to note is that the cup has some duplicate vertices. Make sure to use the "Merge by Distance" tool occasionally to clean those up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This fixed it :)